# Redirect to custom Windows Authentication login page if user anonymous in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, active-directory, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.NET MVC intranet site using Windows Authentication. It's set up from the default project for ASP.NET MVC using Windows Authentication. I've been struggling with finding information on overriding the default login popup if a user is not authenticated / anonymous.

Default login prompt:

[image: Default Windows Auth Login Prompt]

Everything I find on the internet is nearly 10 years old, using classic ASP, or Web Forms. Nothing I can find is using ASP.NET MVC.

What I'd like to do is for the user to be redirected to a Login view if they are anonymous / not authenticated.  Additionally, the ability to log out if they are automatically authenticated and log in as a different user.

The main problem I have is that I can't find where the actual authentication is done in my project. I've checked `App_Start`, `Global.asax`, etc. I can't find how to override it, either.

I know there is a lack of code on my part, but I'd appreciate if someone had a good starting point or experience with this requirement.

Comment: Judging from [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4d0cd8f3-f4be-4fd8-b07b-460214135850/custom-login-page-for-windows-authentication-claims-based?forum=sharepointadminprevious), it looks like you can't create a custom login page for windows authentication. If you want a custom login page, you'll need to use Form-Based Authentication.

Comment: are you using Active Directory?

Comment: @TejasVaishnav Yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well... is not possible to implement a custom login for an IIS site using Integrated Windows Authentication. Reasons:

- Windows Authentication works on a different TCP/IP layer than Form Authentication (if I remember correctly, Internet layer vs Application layer). Also, you have different types and version on Windows authentication to consider (different Kerberos version with NTLM fallback).
- The windows authentication form is build-in into the browser
- An IIS website cannot have mixed authentication (Windows based AND forms based)

However, there are workarounds. I can think of two, for example:

1. Implement a custom membership provider, where you can use, when needed, an impersonation/delegation mechanism
2. Implement a single sign-on architecture, using, for example, ADFS.

Comment: I'll look into ADFS... I've seen other companies use this, now that I think about it. Do you have an example of what you mean by an "impersonation/delegation mechanism"? Is that something controlled by the web.config or at the request or what?

Comment: @justiceorjustus  "Impersonation" means that you run your request/thread/process under the credentials of the caller. "Delegation" means that you access, from your MVC app, external resources (like Sql Server, network shares and files, third party applications) with the credentials of the caller while your thread/process maintain the standard credential (like, for example, the AppPoolIdentity used by the w3wp process).

Comment: @justiceorjustus The first workaround consist in changing the application authentication mode to Form based and make the user sending his username and password with a http request. Server-side, you implement a custom membership that validates the credentials against the target AD and impersonate the user using WindowsPrincipal and WindowsIdentiy classes. Must warn you though: this is a quick and dirty solution with significant security trade-offs. (I'll try to find or create an example when I have time)

Comment: @justiceorjustus The second workaround  is more standard, secure and "civilized" but has its own trade-offs: 1. You need a significantly more complex network architecture and you depend on the AD system administrator for the implementation. 2. From my experience, you have limited customization possibilities for the login form.

Comment: I'll be using ADFS for this feature.  It actually solves a few problems with moving forward with this project, as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can implement forms authentication with your own custom Login page. In the controller code you can check if the given username/password is correct through Windows authentication mechanisms.

We are using it in our MVC application and it just works with Forms Authentication.
You have to implement the authentication against AD on your own. 
After successful authentication you set a cookie

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserId, true);
```

and the user is authenticated on your site.
You need to decorate your controllers with [Authorize] attribute.

Comment: Thanks for this! Any tips or tutorials on how to do that?